# how to add phone numbers to telegram account by using contacts_ImportedContacts method in MadelineProto and php?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a list of phone numbers in an Excel file.
I just want to determine which phone numbers have the telegram accounts?
perhaps somebody would say that it is possible by importring the numbers list to my mobile audience by contact to excel app and then The telegram itself automatically sync the audience's list.
But I have to say that It's not the right way to do it.

After the research, I found that by madelineproto and using the contacts _ ImportedContacts method, this can be done

This is the document link :

https://docs.madelineproto.xyz/API_docs/methods/contacts_importContacts.html

So I installed madelineproto first and activated it and I wrote the following script :

```
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
include 'madeline.php';

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
$MadelineProto->async(true);
$MadelineProto->loop(function () use ($MadelineProto) {
    yield $MadelineProto->start();

    $me = yield $MadelineProto->get_self();

    $MadelineProto->logger($me);

    if (!$me['bot']) {
        yield $MadelineProto->messages->sendMessage(['peer' => '@FS10218', 'message' => "hi my dear friend"]);
        yield $MadelineProto->channels->joinChannel(['channel' => '@Akhbar_Fori_Ir']);
       yield $MadelineProto->contacts->importContacts(['contacts' => [ [ '_'=>[ 'client_id'=>0, 'phone'=>'+12106606046', 'first_name'=>'Ccc', 'last_name'=>'Fff' ] ] ], ]);
    }
    yield $MadelineProto->echo('OK, done!');
});
```

It works correctly to send messages and join to channel.
but doesn't add the phone number to my telegram account.why?

Is this a limit created by the telegram or my code is wrong?

I beforehand apologize for the existence of grammatical mistakes and that my English is weak

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct. Telegram has announced a new privacy setting "Who Can See My Phone Number" [here](https://telegram.org/blog/scheduled-reminders-themes). If this option is set to "Nobody" you can't import the number. The phone number in your code has either enabled this option or is not associated with a Telegram account (I tried to import it myself). Your code should work with another phone number.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$MadelineProto->contacts->importContacts(contacts: [ ['client_id' => long, 'phone' => 'string', 'first_name' => 'string', 'last_name' => 'string'] ] );
```